# How to export the numeric RSA secret key (d) from a GPG keyring

Tags: gnupg, secret-key

I'm using GPG2 with this command to export my GPG keyring:

```
$ gpg --export-secret-key | gpg --list-packets -vvv --debug 0xffff
```

This prints (among others) for RSA keys:

```
   :secret sub key packet:
        version 4, algo 1, created 1576011813, expires 0
        pkey[0]: ABD2...
        pkey[1]: 010001
        iter+salt S2K, algo: 7, SHA1 protection, hash: 2, salt: D476FD990128BDB1
        protect count: 3014656 (183)
        protect IV:  0c 7c 1a d8 ec e3 f0 d4 ac ba bf 46 2a 15 e4 cd
        skey[2]: [v4 protected]
        keyid: E8F5DC1127CAB70F
```

Output of

```
$ gpg --export-secret-key | pgpdump -i -l -m -p
```

is:

```
Old: Secret Subkey Packet(tag 7)(966 bytes)
        Ver 4 - new
        Public key creation time - Tue Dec 10 22:03:33 CET 2019
        Pub alg - RSA Encrypt or Sign(pub 1)
        RSA n(2048 bits) - ab d2 ...
        Sym alg - AES with 128-bit key(sym 7)
        Iterated and salted string-to-key(s2k 3):
                Hash alg - SHA1(hash 2)
                Salt - c2 a0 1f 8f 94 52 f0 a3 
                Count - 3014656(coded count 183)
        IV - 4c 28 ae 9d d6 77 68 f4 67 ce b3 17 4b cf 20 f6 
        Encrypted RSA d
        Encrypted RSA p
        Encrypted RSA q
        Encrypted RSA u
        Encrypted SHA1 hash
```

It looks like `pkey[0]` is *n*, `pkey[1]` is *e* (0x010001 == 65537), and `skey[2]` is *d*. How do I get the unencrypted numeric (hexadecimal) value of *d* printed? (I know the key passphrase.)

Please note that I want to get the actual unencrypted *d* value, and I'm not interested in importing the secret key on another computer running GPG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in https://superuser.com/a/1012873 , after removing the passphrase with `gpg --edit-key ...` (`passwd`, *Enter*, old passphrase, *Enter*, *Enter*, *Enter*, `save`, *Enter*), both commands in the question print *d*, *p*, *q* and *u*.

Then I can add the passphrase back again with `gpg --edit-key ...`.